# Is it possible to have per-project formatter that affect tab key policy in Aptana?

Tags: aptana

I'm trying to setup Aptana to be able to have different PHP formatting rules for different projects.  For instance I work on both Drupal and Codigniter projects.  Drupal coding standard wants 2 spaces for tabs.  Codeigniter wants a single tab that shows up as 4 spaces.

The way I would think to make this happen is as follows:

1. Project > Properties
2. Select "Formatter" from options on the left
3. Click "Enable project specific settings"
4. Click the plus button to create a new profile (eg. call it Drupal)
5. Select "PHP" from the list below "Preview:"
6. Click the edit button pencil
7. Select the indentation tab and set the Tab policy to "Spaces only" with indentation size to 2 and Tab size to 2
8. Click Ok twice to apply the changes.

Then I restart Aptana just to make sure the new settings apply.  However no matter what I do it still seems to use the settings that are set in Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors (Displayed tab width, Insert spaces for tabs).

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I would open a new ticket here: http://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa